# Why does babel translate async/await to regenerators?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, ecmascript-harmony

All version of babel translate an `await` statement to a `_asyncToGenerator` call, it obviously has some shortcomings:

1. Code size grows dramatically
2. Requires the `regeneratorRuntime` library

From my understanding of the syntax I think any `await` should be equivalent to a `Promise#then` call, so the code below:

```
try {
    let user = await getUser();
    console.log(user.name);
}
catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
```

is just equivalent to:

```
let promise$of$getUser$ = getUser();
$promise$of$getUser$.then(
    $result$ => console.log($result$),
    $error$ => console.error($error$)
);
```

In this way it is also possible to correctly map multiple `await` statements or even a mix of `Promise#then` and `await` statements to a `Promise` chain, so I must missed some cases where pure `Promise#then` is not suitable for `await` statements.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the other 2 plugins: [async-to-generator](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-async-to-generator/) and [async-to-module-method](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-async-to-module-method/).

There's also an experimental plugin called [kneden](https://github.com/marten-de-vries/kneden) which does try to do what you are suggesting (async to promise). It's still WIP and doesn't account for all cases and most likely will not be able to.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're overlooking loops:

```
for (let userId of userIds) {
  const user = await getUser(userId);
  console.log(user);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, after some research I find loops and conditions are possible to handle properly but is really hard, mixes of all these complexities may be the reason not to support translating await directly into Promise